# Azure Python function: unable to open image '': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, magickwand

Hello Python Azure Guru's,

I want to creating an **Local Azure Python Function** which read pdf data from file an convert it to "jpeg" therefor i use **imagemagick** and the python binder of imagemagick. First i create the python function and which runs succesfully localy without a "Local Azure Python Function". Then i refactor the code to an Local Azure Python Function" run it and receive the following message.

```
unable to open image 'data/Stephan.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537
```

Below the code of the Python function:

```
def convertToJPEG(pdf_url):
    try:
        print(pdf_url) 
        pdf = wi(filename= pdf_url, resolution= 300)
        print('Read Succesfull')
        pdfImage = pdf.convert('jpeg')
        print('Converted')
        imageBlobs = []
        for img in pdfImage.sequence:
            imgPage = wi(image=img)
            imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))
    
        return imageBlobs
```

Can you please give a solution how to solve this issue! Or are there other methods to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install pdf2image and poppler,

Then do this:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    path = 'data/Stephan.pdf'
    pages = convert_from_path(path, 500)
    for page in pages:
        page.save('data/out.jpg', 'JPEG')
    return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully",
            status_code=200
    )
```

This is the structure of my function app:

[image]